# How to test a Spring Data JPA project

Tags: spring, junit, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring app, with these dependencies. the project contains only the services and repositories of another application, so there is no main class

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I want to test a service, so this is my service class:

I have this config file:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bonanza.backend.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.bonanza.backend.service")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.bonanza/backend-dev.properties")
public class DevBackendConfig {
}
```

and this one on the test package:

```
@Configuration
@Import({DevBackendConfig.class})
public class TestBackendConfig {
}
```

and this is my test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestBackendConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CompanyServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    protected CompanyService companyService;

..
}
```

but when I run the test I have this error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#636e8cc' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#636e8cc': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that spring can't create bean for user JPA repo. It's ok, cause if you're doing unit test you should test only one layer of your application and mock the dependencies. This can be done with the help [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) framework. [Here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/stubbing-and-mocking-with-mockito-2-and-junit) is the nice introduction blog post. Resulting test code will look like this (we mocked all dependencies and created stubs where needed):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestUserResolver {
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Mock
private RightsRequestRepository rightsRequestRepository;
@Mock
private NotifierService notifierService;

private UserResolver userResolver;

@Test
public void testListAllUsers() {
    when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(getFakeUserList());
    userResolver = new UserResolver(userRepository, rightsRequestRepository, notifierService);

    List<UserDTO> cs = userResolver.getAllUsers();
    assertEquals(1, cs.size());
}
....}
```